# How to convert this correlated sub query to Vertica friendly non correlated query

Tags: vertica

I have below SQL Server query and need to convert it to Vertica query.
The problem right now is vertica doesnt support multi-level correlated subqueries so in my example and `t3.a = t1.a` doesnt work

```
select * from t1
    where not exists (
      select * from t2
      where t2.y = t1.y 
      and t2.x in (
          select top 1 x from t3
          where t3.z = t2.z
          and t3.a = t1.a
          order by t3.b
          )
     )
```

Can anyone please help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertica doesn't support more than 1 level of correlated sub-queries, you should convert them into JOINs.

It also doesn't support the TOP x clause, use LIMIT x instead.

Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.y = t2.y
WHERE t2.y IS NULL
  AND t2.x IN
    (SELECT t3.x
     FROM t3
     JOIN t2 ON t3.z = t2.z
     JOIN t1 ON t3.a=t1.a
     ORDER BY t3.b LIMIT 1);
```